# How to make JUnit templates in Android studio

Tags: java, testing, android-studio, junit, code-templates

I know that since Android studio 1.1 you can now run unit tests in Android studio, and I want to create a JUnit test in Android studio but I can't find a premade class for this.

How can I make a JUnit test class template so that I won't have to write everything manually every time?

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio you can indeed create your own class templates for unit testing.

### How to create a template:

In the top menu, got to `file > Settings` and in the settings. In the left menu, find `Editor > File and Code templates` and click on the green plus symbol.

[image: Illustration on where to click to make a new template]

You can select what language you want it to extend next to the name input.

One example JUnit template could be:

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ${NAME} {
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        
    }
}
```

**Note:**

For the tests to work you need to make sure that you have added JUnit (or whichever unit testing framework you want to add) to the dependencies of your project (add the jar to you `/lib`, `pom.xml`, or `build.gradle`.